For Polish $X,Y$, $L^p(X,Y)$ is separable
Let $X$ and $Y$ be Polish spaces. Equip $X$ with a Borel probability measure $\mu_X$ and $Y$ with a metric $d_Y$. We can define the $L^p$ space as follows:
Definition. Define
$\begin{align}L^p(X,Y) = \left\{f:X\to Y|f\textrm{ is measurable and }\int_{X}d(f(x),y_0)^p<\infty \textrm{for some }y_0\in Y\right\}\end{align}$
and equip $L^p(X,Y)$ by the following metric:
$\displaystyle \begin{equation}D_p(f,g) = \left(\int_{X}d_Y(f(x),g(x))^pd\mu_X\right)^{1/p}\end{equation}$
where $d_Y$ is the metric for $Y$.
Question. I would like to prove that $L^p$ is separable. By the argument similar to the $Y=\mathbb{R}$ case, we can prove that $L^p$ is complete, so this would prove that $L^p$ is Polish.
My Attempt.
I tried to adapt the proof for $Y=\mathbb{R}$ to our general case. I used the proof from Haim Brezis's "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces, and Partial Differential Equations." The following is the proof from the book. Note that they consider the case $X=\mathbb{R}^N$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\mathcal{R}$ denote the countable family of sets of the form $R= \prod_{k=1}^{N}$ with $a_k,b_k\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{E}$ denote the vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by the functions $(\chi_R)_{R\in \mathcal{R}}$, that is, $\mathcal{E}$ consist of finite linear combinations with rational coefficients of functions $\chi_R$, so that $\mathcal{E}$ is countable.
We claim that $\mathcal{E}$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Indeed, given $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $f_1 \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $\|f-f_1\|_P<\epsilon$. Let $R\in \mathcal{R}$ be any cube containing $\textrm{supp }{f_1}$ (the support of $f_1$). Given $\delta>0$ it is easy to construct a function $f_2\in \mathcal{E}$ such that $\|f_1-f_2\|<\delta$ and $f_2$ vanishes outside $R$: it suffices to split $R$ into small cubes of $\mathcal{R}$ where the oscilaltion (i.e., $\sup-\inf$) of $f_1$ is less than $\delta$. Therefore, we have $\|f_1-f_2\|_{p}\leq \|f_1-f_2\|_{\infty}|R|^{1/p}<\delta |R|^{1/p}$. We conclude that $\|f-f_2\|_p<2\epsilon$, provided $\delta>)$ is chosen so that $\delta|R|^{1/p}<\epsilon$.

The first roadblock adapting this proof is that Brezis use the density of the space of compactly supported continuous functions. In a general setting, this is not true, so we need to adopt a new strategy. In particular, we can use Lusin's theorem. By Lusin, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a compact set $K\subset X$ such that $\mu_X(K^c)<\epsilon$ and $f|_{K}$ is continuous. Therefore, we can define a new function as follows: define $\tilde{f}:X\to Y$ to be equal to $f$ on $K$ and $y_0$ otherwise, where $y_0$ is some fixed element on $Y$. This function satisfies
$\displaystyle D_p(f,\tilde{f}) = \left(\int_{K^c}d(f(x),y_0)^pd\mu_X\right)^{1/p}\tag*{} $
Assuming $f$ is bounded, this can be bounded by $M\epsilon$ for some constant $M$.
We will now approximate $\tilde{f}$ on $K$. As a substitute for $\mathcal{R}$, we consider open balls $\mathcal{U}=\{U_{r}(c)\}_{c\in C,r\in \mathbb{Q}\cap (0,\infty)}$ where $C$ is a countable subset of $X$ such that $\bar{C}=X$. Since $K$ is compact, we can cover $K$ by finitely many elements in $\mathcal{U}$.
We would want to cover $K$ by $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^{n} \subset \mathcal{U}$ such that the oscillation of $f$ on $U_i$ is small enough i.e. $\sup_{x,x'\in U_i\cap K}d(f(x),f(x'))<\delta$ for any $i$. However, this is not as easy as Brezis's proof since it is hard to subdivide balls into smaller balls.
For this reason, I instead considered taking the family of sets $\mathcal{I}$ containing $\mathcal{U}$ and their finitely many intersections. In this case, we can subdivide balls into smaller finitely many elements in $\mathcal{I}$ by covering a ball with too large oscillation by finitely many smaller balls and then taking the intersection with the larger ball, but I could not figure out how to make sure the "oscillation" above would be small enough.
Any hints and ideas?

$y_0$ is independent of $f$ (fixed) or depends on $f$?

@DieterKadelka Independent of $f$. It is like a replacement of $0$ in the original proof.

Note that by  Fréchet-Kuratowski ,  $Y$ embeds isometrically  as a closed subset of  a separable Banach space $E$  (also sending $y_0$ to $0$)   so $L^p(X,Y)$ is a closed subspace of the Bochner-Lebesgue space  $L^p(X,E)$.

@PietroMajer Interesting, digging more into Lebesgue-Bochner spaces, I found that If $L^p(\mu)$ and $X$ are separable, then $L^p(\mu, X)$ is separable as well (cited from Theorem 15 here). Am I correct in saying that this proves our proposition positively?

Yes I think so  :)

And btw the fact that  $L^p$ functions $f:X\to Y\subset E$ are in fact  strongly measurable, therefore in the Bochner $L^p$ space, comes from the Pettis measurability theorem

@PietroMajer Do you have any references for what you mentioned? The pdf I linked has no proofs so I would want a better reference.

I should check; however every textbook on Bochner integral usually has the Pettis measurability criterion

E.g.  the wonderful  Functional Analysis  by Yosida

@PietroMajer Sorry to revive the thread, but how do I embed $Y$ to a separable Banach space? In the usual statement of Fréchet-Kuratowski, we either use $l^\infty$ or the space of bounded continuous functions, but I believe none of them are separable.

@PietroMajer Never mind, I found it in Banach's Theory of Linear Operation (Page 113) that I can embed it to $C([0,1])$, which is indeed separable.

But if Y is embedded in a Banach space, the closure of span Y is a separable Banach space, as Y
